# how I can add text out of figure in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In my scientific work, I must add numbers and arrows out of picture, in the side.

Would you please help me?

Comment: Closed as it's difficult to tell what's being asked here.  If you can clarify and flag the question for reopening, a mod will be happy to assist.

Answer (score 1):

okay its based on what i understood

The basic way :

open your Photoshop

create a new document (remember you have to create new document size more than your current project picture)
suppose your picture is 500*700 though you have to create something bigger than that such as 580*700.

place/drag your picture in this new document see there are some space both side, which you can use to put your arrow and numbers.

---

The good way :

open your project picture press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> this will open your canvas something like that

[image]

you can add some more pixel to increase you work space as i did in this SS click any arrow left or right wherever  you need space.

after getting the space you can put your arrow and numbers together

hope this is clear to you....